# I have github private email checked, but I still received an email from someone on an older repo?

Tags: github

So I originally had my emails public and pushed majority of my repos online without hiding my email. I recently switch my profile settings to make my emails private and not to display it, but today I received an email to my profile email and I don't know how they found it.

If I check the settings to private email, but I have older repos where I uploaded the code without hiding my email, would github update all of my old repos to switch my email to private?

Or would I manually have to redo the history of the old repos to prevent people from seeing my email?

Also, if someone emails you from your github hidden email, would it show in your gmail as a regular email? or isn't it supposed to be shown as sent to email-2323-VWxer-2@email.com?